# How to add current timestamp to Date object in Java?

Tags: java, date

I need to pass in a `Date` object into a service which my API is calling. I have the info on the day, month, and year for the `Date` but also need a timestamp. The service is expecting it in this format:

```
<date>2015-04-01T00:00:00-05:00</date>
```

How can I add something to the Date to get this format?

Comment: Do you need a `String` or a `Date`? Your Question is not clear.

Comment: Date object the service takes in a protected Date effectiveDate;

Comment: A `String` is not a `Date`. If the code takes a `Date` object, why do you show a String in your Question?

Answer (score 4):

Never use `java.util.Date`. Supplanted by `java.time.Instant`.

Get your date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2015 , 4 , 1 ) ;
```

Or use the readable `Month` enum.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.APRIL , 1 ) ;
```

Get the time of day when the day starts in some particular time zone. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00, may be some other time such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* figure that out for you.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Generate a string in your desired format, a standard ISO 8601 format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

To see that moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

## Conversion

If you must inter-operate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can call new conversion methods added to the old classes. These include [`Date::from( Instant )`](https://docs.oracle.com/../../java/util/Date.html#from(java.time.Instant)).

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;
```

Get back to a time zone other than UTC.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't think I can pass an Instant to this service. It needs to be a "Date" object. Is there a way to convert between the two?

Comment: I know the Date class isn't great and is deprecated but I am restricted by what this service requires as input

Comment: This is what I have in the client code I generated:

Comment: @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
 protected Date effectiveDate;

Comment: @Connie I added a “Conversion” section. This is covered on existing Q&A on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Connie Check your library you are using for XML. It is likely updated to be savvy with *java.time*. The *java.time* classes have been out for years, built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it and see you are probably right

Answer (score 1):

Working with dates in Java is an ugly mess, always has been. Date class is mostly deprecated now. I am using LocalDateTime where you can construct it by calling **year, month, day, hour, minute, and seconds**. Here is what I could come up with:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(1997, Month.SEPTEMBER, 2, 1, 23, 0);
ZonedDateTime systemTime = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME; //Basil's idea
System.out.println(systemTime.format(formatter));
```

Output:

```
1997-09-02T01:23:00-05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use SimpleDateFormat for this.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Poor advice. These troublesome classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time classes.